# MLA Page #s in a group essay?

Tags: mla

For the Page #, it normally should be [My last name], [Page #], correct? What do I do to format the Page # properly in a group project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about formatting an essay, and not English Language & Usage.

Comment: Your best bet is to look up MLA guidelines or speak to your teacher. Good luck!

Comment: You'll likely get a better reception to this question at [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). However, even there you need to clarify what you're asking, since it's not really clear. The page number remains the same no matter what. How you cite multiple people depends on several factors. You normally cite them in the order that they appear in the publication itself. And you can use first names or initials if two have the same last name. If there are more than three authors, you use the primary author followed by *et al.*. But you should give the specific variables.